# Ask SQL for multiplication two columns and then division with sum of some rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables

**scores**

```
id name score item_id
----------------------    
1   rikad  90  1
2   rikad  80  2
3  rikad 70 3
4  reza 80 1
5  reza 80 2
6  reza 100 3
```

**items**

```
id weight
----------
1  0.5
2  0.2
3  0.3
```

I want the output with new column call last_score ( (score x weight ) / "0.5 + 0.2 + 0.3 (sum of all weight that have same name)" )

```
id name score item_id weight last_score
----------------------------------------
1   rikad  90  1 0.5  last_score
2   rikad  80  2 0.2 last_score
3  rikad 70 3 0.3 last_score
4  reza 80 1 0.5 last_score
5  reza 80 2 0.2 last_score
6  reza 100 3 0.3 last_score
```

I have tried this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    scores.id, scores.name,
    items.id, items.weight, 
    scores.score * items.weight AS 'last_score'
FROM 
    scores
JOIN 
    items ON items.id = scores.item_id
```

I need to division the last score with the sum of all weight that have same name. But I have no idea to sum the weight.

Comment: This is a Q/A site, so it would not hurt, if you actually asked a question. Along with asking a question, you could also describe what you have tried to achieve the desired output!

Comment: i have tried this sql "SELECT scores.id, scores.name,items.id,items.weight, scores.score * items.weight AS 'last_score' from scores JOIN items ON items.id = scores.item_id "  ,, i need to division the last score with the sum of all weight that have same name

Comment: but i have no idea to sum the weight,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the sum of weights by name and join this back on the main tables using the name field:

```
SELECT scores.id, scores.name,items.id,items.weight, scores.score * items.weight/t.sum_weight AS 'last_score'
from scores
INNER JOIN items ON items.id = scores.item_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT scores.name, sum(items.weight) sum_weight
            FROM scores INNER JOIN items ON items.id = scores.item_id
            GROUP BY scores.name) t ON scores.name=t.name
```

Comment: thank you very much, use sub query is the answer.. :)

Answer (score -1):

select S.id,S.name,S.score,S.item_id,I.[weight],
 (cast(S.score as float) * cast(I.[weight] as float))/ sum(cast([weight] as float))  as LastScore
 from scores S inner join items I
 on s.id = i.id
  group by S.id,S.name,S.score,S.item_id,I.[weight]

Comment: hmm i new on sql, and dont undertand your sql, seems like not basic sql , i will try this and learn later...   thank for u answer